# Heat Map of user interaction with a touchscreen application (Android, iOS)

Tags: android, ios, visualization, touchscreen, heatmap

I noticed there are a large number of player guides on YouTube that show a "heat map" or visual of typical user interaction with a touchscreen application, like this example:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H5mVS1sEAZI

I have an Android application being used for research purposes, and we are already tracking (in a SQLLite database) when and where users touch / interact with a video.

We would love to create a visualization of where and when users are touching the screen.

Are there any tools, APIs, etc. out there that anyone has seen for generating this kind of data visualization?

If not, is there any good way to take screenshots of the video / application at a moment in time when users touch the application?

Answer (score 0):

For iOS you can use https://heatma.ps SDK